# Mi tabla en la BD no registra los datos enviados

Tags: php, mysql

el problema es el siguiente.
Creé un formulario que registra los datos en una tabla (dentro de una BD), pero por algún motivo al revisar mi gestor de BD (heidisql 8.2) noto que la tabla está vacía, que no se registró nada. Revisé mi código varias veces y según yo, tengo todo bien, les muestro lo que escribí, desde ya, gracias.

Este es el código del formulario (en ningún lado me salta un mensaje de error y el código fluye hasta la última parte)

```
<div id="contenido">
  <fieldset id="formulario">
     <legend>Insertar</legend>
        <form id="datosform" action="procesoinsertar.php" method="POST">
           <table>
<!---Nombre------------------------------------------------>
             <tr>
               <td>Nombre:</td>
                 <td>
                   <input id="nom" type="text" name="nom" maxlength="50"title="Máximo 50 carácteres">
                 </td>
             </tr>
<!---Dirección------------------------------------------------>
             <tr>
               <td>Dirección:</td>
                 <td>
                   <input id="dir" type="text" name="dir" maxlength="100"title="Máximo 100 carácteres">
                 </td>
             </tr>
<!---Dirección------------------------------------------------>
            <tr>
              <td>Teléfono:</td>
                <td>
                  <input id="tel" type="text" name="tel" maxlength="15" value="+598" title="Máximo 15 dígitos">
                </td>
            </tr>
<!---Dirección------------------------------------------------>
              <tr>
                <td>Departamento:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input id="dep" type="text" name="dep" maxlength="30" title="Máximo 30 carácteres">
                  </td>
              </tr>
<!---Botones------------------------------------------------>
           <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="CheckForm();">
                <input type="reset" value="Cancelar">
              </td>
           </tr>
```

Este el del "CheckForm"

```
document.getElementById("datosform").submit();
```

Este la parte final en donde lo manda

```
<?php

include "../2.inc/conexion.inc";

$nombre         = utf8_decode($_POST["nom"]);
$direccion      = utf8_decode($_POST["dir"]);
$telefono       = $_POST["tel"];
$departamento   = utf8_decode($_POST["dep"]);

$sql  = "INSERT INTO personas ";
$sql .= "(id,nom,dir,tel,dep) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ";
$sql .= "(null,'$nombre','$direccion','$telefono','$departamento')";

mysqli_query($conexion);

mysqli_close($conexion);

header("location: insertar.php");

 ?>
```

Por las dudas les dejo la prueba de conexión

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vitabar");

if(!$conexion) {
        header("Location: error.php?mensaje= No se pudo conectar con la base de datos");
}

?>
```

Comment: hacer rato que no trabajo php pero creo que las variables '$nombre','$direccion','$telefono','$departamento' no deben ir en comillas

Comment: además deberías tener algo asi mysqli_query($connección, $sql)... recuerda no usar aceptos en el código te puede generar errores, además conexión es la palabra en español correcta

Comment: @ger, las variables sí deben ir entre comillas simples cuando son del tipo `VARCHAR`, las que no llevan comillas son las que son numéricas. Andrés, el problema puede deberse a que no se está mandando la consulta en esta llamada `mysqli_query($conneción);`. Revisa la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), `mysqli_query` necesita un 2º parámetro que es la consulta SQL a ejecutar. Te sugiero que evites el uso de acentos o caracteres espaciales para nombrar variables u otros elementos como tablas, columnas, bases de datos, etc.

Comment: @Marcos está en spanglish, pues en español es conexión y en inglés es connection y en espanglish puede ser conneción u otra cosa. Andrés, hablando de acentos, tampoco necesitas desarrollar una dependencia de `utf8_decode` para cada dato que vayas a tratar, basta con que configures adecuadamente el entorno a `utf8`: a nivel de documento (HTML), de servidor (PHP) y de base de datos (conexión y datos en sí). Así no tienes que estar aplicado `utf8_decode` que además muchas veces no funciona si no hay una configuración del contexto, la cual prevalece sobre esta función.

Comment: Prueba a quitar el onclick en el input y pon un type="submit" a ver si te funciona.